# How do I use Django's MarkUp Templates Tags with Google App Engine WebApp Framework

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates, markup

I'm using Google App Engine WebApp Framework which works with Django's Templates. I'm trying to use Django's MarkUp filters and the instructions say:

- Put django.contrib.markup in your INSTALLED_APPS
- Load markup in your templates via {% load markup %}
- Filter whatever text with the appropriate filter: {{ text|textile }}

My question is since I'm using the webapp framework I don't have a "INSTALLED_APP" middleware. Does anyone know how I can load this module in webapp?

Comment: Have you tried something like this? http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-custom-django-template-helpers.html

Answer (score 4):

#### Set up tag library:

Create a folder in your app directory, **`customtags`** for example.

Within this folder create an empty `__init__.py` file

in the same folder create your tags file **`customtags.py`** for example

At the beginning of 'customtags.py' add the following lines

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
register = webapp.template.create_template_register()
```

Add your new tag library to your main.py file like so:

```
template.register_template_library('customtags.customtags')
```

Assuming you already have:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
```

#### Create your tags like so:

**Filter tag:**

```
@register.filter
def foobar(value):
    return value
```

call from template like so:

```
{{ something|foobar }}
```

**Simple tag:**

```
@register.simple_tag
def mysimpletag():
    print 'hello from the simple tag'
```

call from template like so:

```
{% mysimpletag %}
```

**Inclusion tag:**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('templates/menu.html')
def menu():
    items = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Pages')
    return {'items':items}
```

call from templte like so:

```
{% menu %}
```

Comment: The user didn't ask how to create his own tags, he asked how to load an existing library.